# Why is my very simple neural network not doing at all well?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I have created an extremely simple neural network to help my understanding. It has one neuron, and one input, and one weight. The idea is simple: given many random numbers between 0,200, learn that anything over 100 is correct, and under 100 is in correct (instead of just being told).

```
import random

weight = random.uniform(-1,1)


def train(g,c,i):
    global weight
    weight = weight + (i*(c-g)) #change weight by error change 
    if(g==c):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def trial(i):
    global weight
    sum = i*weight 
    if(sum>0):
        return 1
    else:
        return -1


def feedData():
    suc = 0
    for x in range(0,10000):
        d = random.randint(0,200)
        if(d>100): #tell what is correct and not (this is like the dataset)
            correct = 1
        else:
            correct = -1

        g = trial(d)
        if(train(g,correct, d)==True):
             suc += 1


    print(suc)


feedData();
```

Out of 10000, I would expect at least 8000 to be correct. However, it always ranges between 4990 and 5100 success.

I obviously have a slight flaw in my understanding. Cheers for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem here is that you're lacking a bias term.  The network you've built is multiplying a positive integer (`d`) by a weight value, and then comparing the result to see if it's positive or negative.  In an ideal universe, what should the value of `weight` be?  If `weight` is positive, the network will get about 50% of the inputs right; if it's negative, it will also be right about 50% of the time.

You'll see that the network can't solve this problem, until you introduce a second "weight" as a bias term.  If you have `sum = i * weight + bias`, and you also update `bias` in `train`, then you should be able to correctly classify all inputs.  I would initialise `bias` the same way as `weight`, and then do the update as:

```
bias = bias + (c-g)
```

Bias terms are often used in machine learning systems to account for a "bias" or "skew" in the input data (e.g., in a spam email classifier, maybe 80-95% of emails that we get are not spam, so the system should be biased against marking something as spam).  In this case, the bias will allow the network to learn that it should produce some negative outputs, but all of your inputs are positive values.

To put it another way, let's think of linear algebra.  Your input classes (that is, {x|x<100} and {x|x>100}) are linearly separable.  The function that separates them is something like y = x - 100.  This is a straight line on a 2D plot, which has positive slope, and intersects the y axis at y = -100, and the x axis at x = 100.  Using this line, you can say that all values for x under 100 map to negative values of y (i.e., are incorrect), and all those above 100 map to positive values of y (i.e., are correct).

The difficulty with your code is that you can only express lines which go through the origin (because you're lacking a bias term).

Comment: sounds interesting. could you explain in more detail how to incorporate this? I thought a bias was simply for if the input was 0 or unset, it would bias to either correct or incorrect ... my understanding is not that relevant then is it!

Comment: thanks for the in depth answer (upvote) , what should the bias start as ? rand between -1,1?

Comment: Sure, it shouldn't matter too much for your case.  If I initialise `bias` the same way as `weight` (uniform on [-1,1]), then I can get 63-98% correct with your code.

Comment: have tried now, and yes! managed to get 6000-9000 success, but still a little confused about bias, ill try turn my confusing into a question: because the random number (or data) is 50/50, what and how is it bias to? using your spam analogy, in this case, what is the spam? Huge thanks. also accepting as answer youve been really helpful.

Comment: Hm.  The bias is due to a mismatch between the input range and the output domain.  Your inputs are all positive (x is always between 0 and 200), whereas about 50% of your outputs need to be negative (because 50% of the time, x is "incorrect").  So, you might say that all your inputs are "too high", and that this is the bias.  For instance, if your criterion in `trial` was `sum > 100` instead of `sum > 0`, then it would be OK if all of your outputs were positive, and you would be able to converge on a good solution.

Comment: ah that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Note: if you change the criterion to `sum > 100`, you also need to introduce a learning rate parameter like this: `weight = weight + 0.1 * (i*(c-g))`.  Gradient descent methods usually adjust weights slowly by multiplying the error gradient by a small learning rate (a value like 0.1 or 0.01, or something else that magically happens to work).  This stops your weight value from bouncing around so much, and lets you converge to a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

This is mostly because of this line

`d = random.randint(0,200)`

By the problem itself, you have 50% chances to get the right number (>100). If you increase the maximum value from 200 to 500 as example, you'll get closer to what you want.

You need to find a better way to generate random number or to create your own algorithm for this.

Comment: surely thats just because it is a higher chance of getting it wrong? not because it is doing a good job in learning anything?